# Insertar en SQLite con C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, sqlite3

Con la tabla "usuarios" creada, me dispongo a introducir datos en la misma. Estos datos son introducidos por el usuario, para después insertarse en la tabla.
Tengo la siguiente función:

```
int registrarUsuario(string name, string second){
            sqlite3 *db;
            int conn;
            int exec;
            string sql;

            // Abriendo conexion con la base de datos
            conn = sqlite3_open("usuarios.db", &db);
            if(SQLITE_OK != conn){
                system("clear");
                cerr << "\E[1;31mImposible introducir los datos datos\E[0;00m" << endl;
                cin.get();
                cin.sync();
                sqlite3_close(db);
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                system("clear");
                // Creando datos SQL
                sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre,Apellidos) VALUES("+ name + "," + second + ");";
                // Introduciendo datos SQL
                exec = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
                if( SQLITE_OK == exec){
                    cout << "\E[1;32mDatos introducidos con exito\E[0;00m" << endl;
                    cin.get();
                    cin.sync();
                    sqlite3_close(db);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Una vez introducidos, se llama a la función con esos parámetros.
El problema está en que cuando se llama a la función se cierra completamente el programa.

Comment: Deberías probar a depurar el código y ver en qué punto se está cerrando el programa... con el código que expones es complicado saber qué está pasando.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que están insertando mal los campos y tienes un punto y coma de más al final. Debería de ser de esta forma:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre,Apellidos) VALUES('"+ name + "','" + second + "')";
```

Aunque te recomiendo que uses Try/Catch y así saber tu excepción